# could not find a module after add new package in docker

Tags: node.js, docker

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine
WORKDIR "/test"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

and here is my dockerCompose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: "."
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - . :/test/
      - /test/node_modules
```

When I add a new package and run docker-compose build, npm install called correctly but when I restart my container it gives me that package doesn't install. I'll fix it by docker-compose down -v but I couldn't understand why should I remove a volume after install a new package.

Comment: Since you’ve told Docker (via `volumes:`) that your `node_modules` tree contains critical application data, Docker will never update it, even if you rebuild your image; it will leave your application data intact.

Comment: @DavidMazeThanks so much